# Datanode, tasktracker dies when executing hadoop fs -put command

Tags: hadoop

I have a hadoop cluster with 1 master(running namenode and jobtracker) and 2 slaves(running datanode and tasktracker on each). Now whenever I execute

```
hadoop fs -put localfile /user/root/tmp/input
```

for 4-8 GB of data, the command executes perfectly.

But when I increase the data to 30GB one of the slaves dies. As in I get an java.io.noRouteToHost exception and the command exits unsuccessfully. Immediately I did ping to that slave and found that even the Ethernet connection is down. So I have to manually do

```
ifup eth0
```

on that slave to bring the host up again.
I am not able to figure out the problem here. I also changed the following properties

```
dfs.socket.timeout,  for read timeout
dfs.datanode.socket.write.timeout, for write timeout
```

I increased the read timeout to 600000 and write timeout I changed to 0 to make it infinity. Please any suggestions. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. The problem was with hardware. Though my NIC card was Gigabit the switch in which all the nodes were plugged was 100MBps supported. Changed the switch to Gigabit and worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using "distCp" to copy large data.

Comment: But as far as I know "distCp" is used for intra cluster transfer of large data. Not for transferring data from local file system to HDFS. I'm facing the above problem while transfering from local FS to HDFS. Sorry if I was not precise.

Comment: you can use it for that as well. try to use something like this : cluster@tariq:~/hadoop-1.0.3$ bin/hadoop distcp file:///home/cluster/pig-0.9.1/ hdfs://localhost:9000/pig/

Answer (score -1):

I faced a smiliar problem and I used `-copyFromLocal` instead of -put and it resolved the issue.

h`adoop fs -copyFromLocal localfile /user/root/tmp/input`